# Converting sqlite (spatialite) data to oracle sdo_geometry (using .NET)

Tags: spatialite, oracle-spatial

Using .NET, I have a sqlite file that I have to import to oracle.  The geometry needs to be converted from sqlite (spatialite) geometry column to a sdo_geometry column in oracle:

```
// Loop through all records in sqlite file
foreach (DataRow row in dsSqLite.Tables["Default"].Rows)
{
  // Get geometry field from sqlite and get it ready for oracle format
  NetSdoGeometry.sdogeometry geom = row["GEOMETRY"];  // ERROR HERE
}
```

When I execute the above, I get an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'NetSdoGeometry.sdogeometry'.  Also I do not see where to specify the SRID.  Does anyone know the correct way to convert the geometry column from spatialite to oracle sdo_geometry?

References:
NetSdoGeometry library: https://github.com/mapspiral/NetSdoGeometry

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, NetSdoGeometry works only by READING geometries from Oracle into some .net object. I don't see a place where it does the reverse.

Maybe a much simpler solution is to use gdal (ogr2ogr) do copy the content from sqlite into Oracle. See http://www.gdal.org/drv_sqlite.html for details about that driver.